# Angular ui click not working

Tags: angularjs

I try to use angular-ui in my app, but cant resolve one small problem. For example, I try to use accordeon. All works well on clean page like on plunker, but in my real app not working click event. I include in my module

```
    angular.module('moduleName', ['ui.bootstrap', 'myFilters', 'my1Services', 'my2Services'])
```

my includes

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/services.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
 <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
 <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

I try to click on the header

```
<accordion-group heading="Static Header">
            This content is straight in the template.
</accordion-group>
```

But nothing happen. The code below must open by click on the header

```
<accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
            {{group.content}}
</accordion-group>
```

Why click not working? Thanks

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Using http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview it looks like you need to rethink your hierarchy. to be <accordion><accordion-group heading="Static Header">content></accordion-group></accordion>

Comment: no, there are no any errors. just not open by click

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in styles: standart bootstrap styles 3.0 not working with combined styles 2.3. example:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```